# DI method with inf limits

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, quantum-mechanics

Been at this forever amount of hours now, looking around online, asking fellow students etc. Couldn't find a thread about this, so here goes:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\big(\frac{-x^2}{a^2}\big)}x^2 \,dx\space\space\space\space\space$ (1)

DI-method table setup gives me:

\begin{array}{|sign|D|I|}
\hline
 & D & I\\ \hline
+ & x^2 & e^{\big(\frac{-x^2}{a^2}\big)} \\ \hline
- & 2x &  a^2\sqrt{\pi} \\ \hline
+ & 2 &  xa^2\sqrt{\pi} \\ \hline
- & 0 &  \frac{1}{2}x^2a^2\sqrt{\pi} \\ \hline
\end{array}

This would, if I'm doing the method correctly, allow me to get rid of the integral altogether (because of the $0$ in the D-column at the bottom):

$x^2 \cdot a^2\sqrt{\pi} -x^2a^2\sqrt{\pi} + 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}x^2a^2\sqrt{\pi} = 0 \space\space\space\space\space (2)$

So, that would make the integral I'm looking to solve:
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\big(\frac{-x^2}{a^2}\big)}x^2 \,dx = 0$, which it's not supposed to be.

I have a solution given with partial integration, which I'm not interested in, as I'm doubling down on the DI-method. The answer is supposed to be $\frac{a^2}{2}$. Surely, this must be solvable with the DI-method as well as with the partial integration formula?

Where do I go wrong?

Comment: When using IBP to compute $\int uv$, you cannot put limits in the $\int v$ part and simplify. You have to completely compute the indefinite integral, simplify and then put limits.

Comment: Also, I think you either copied the problem wrong or your answer key is incorrect: the given integral equals $\dfrac{1/2\times \Gamma(1/2)}{(1/a^2)^{1+1/2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}{2(1/a^2)^{3/2}}=\dfrac{|a|^3\sqrt\pi}2$ for real $a$ by first noting that the function is even, then substituting $t=x^2$ and using standard Laplace transform results.

Comment: The first value of the column "I" was wrong, it had an extra $x^2$.

I think I undertstand what you mean though, I have, in the "I" column put limits in order to calculate the integral. Will rework and see where I end up! :) Thank you very much!!!

Added numbering to the formulas:
Otherwise I do believe that (1) should be correct, at least that's how it's written in the problem. :)

To add, this is a quantum mechanics problem initially, I'm trying to calculate the standard deviation $\Delta x$. Already have the answer to $<x>^2$, so am here working on finding $<x^2>$

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, I would have to work with the error function, erf, as the indefinite integral?